# When I search my new YouTube name it doesn't show up

Tags: youtube

I changed my YouTube name, but when I search my new username on YouTube it doesn't show up but, if I search up my old username my videos then my channel comes up.

When I click on the channel, my old username changes back to my new one. Please help I have tried everything including the Google account change name, the YouTube Studios change name but the problem still occurs. It shows up with my new username.

Comment: Welcome. All upper case titles are no allowed, by the other hand some important details are missing like when you changed your "youtube name" and were exactly are you searching your new name, youtube.com, google.com or other place.

Comment: give it a time. name change is not instant. YT needs to process it first and just after that you can have behavior you expect from it

Comment: I search my new name on YouTube

Answer (score 1):

This is purely a matter of allowing sufficient time for Youtube's index to be updated. Changes like this don't show up immediately.

I experienced a similar thing when updating thumbnails of videos. They didn't show immediately but when I checked the following day they had updated.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a time. The name change is not an instant thing. YouTube needs to process it first and just after that, you can have the behaviour you expect from it - eg search your new name.